# Solve in integers $y^2 = x^3 + (x+4)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations, integers

Solve in integers $y^2 = x^3 + (x+4)^2$

$$y^2 = x^3 + (x+4)^2$$
$$y^2 = x^3 + x^2 + 8x + 16$$
$$y^2 - x^2 = x^3 + 8x + 16$$
$$(y+x)(y-x) = x^3 + 8(x+2)$$

How to I continue? I know I should get the form $(ax^b+c)(dy^e+f) = g$ and then factor the combinations but I'm not sure how to get there. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Sorry about that, I added what I've done so far. I'm not sure if this is even in the right direction though.

Comment: I would try factoring $y^2- (x+4)^2$

Comment: You can get $2$ easy solutions by setting $x=0$. I don't think there are any other solutions (*Magma* says there aren't), but I don't have a proof. Maybe there is some way to use congruence conditions.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I was able to bash out $(x, y) = (0, \pm 4)$, but I think I have to prove that there are no other solutions

Comment: Also, after the difference of squares, what should I do if I have $(y-x-4)(y+x+4) = x^3$ I don't think this is enough for the end factoring part. Thanks!

Comment: The right side is even foe any $x,$ so $y$ must be even.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cubic Diophantine with two variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928843/cubic-diophantine-with-two-variables) There is this one also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2047812/399263

Comment: $x\not\equiv 1\pmod 4.$